# Errors with Laravel when adding an IF statement

Tags: php, laravel

I've recently inherited some websites from the developer that was here before me, and I'm having trouble adding a simple IF statement to his code.

The page simply says that "an error has occurred" and there's nothing being written to the logs folder.

Here is the code:

```
protected function sendContactEmail($data)
{
    $enquiry = $data['enquiry'];
    $email = $data['email'];
    $name = $data['name'];

    if($enquiry=='General Enquiry'){
        $to = '********';
        $cc = '********';
    }
    else if($enquiry=='Product Feedback'){
        $to = '********';
        $cc = '********';
    }
    else { //Trade Enquiry
        $to = '********';
    } 

    //email to admin
    Mail::send('contact.email.contact-admin', $data, function ($message) use ($enquiry) {
        $message->from('no-reply@********.com.au', '********');
        $message->replyTo('no-reply@********.com.au', '********');
        $message->subject($enquiry);
        $message->to($to);
        $message->cc($cc);
    });

    //email to user
    Mail::send('contact.email.contact-user', $data, function ($message2) use ($email) {
        $message2->from('no-reply@********.com.au', '********');
        $message2->replyTo('no-reply@********.com.au', '********');
        $message2->subject('********');
        $message2->to($email);
    });
}
```

Anyone got any ideas on where to start?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Is your environment set to DEV?

Comment: `$cc` isn't given a default value. When `$enquiry` is matches none of the conditions, `$cc` is never initialized.

Comment: @fubar v5.4.16 and no.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule - I didn't know they need to be initialised. When the script tries to use the variable, it will always have been defined by that point. However, I added defaults anyway and it hasn't fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `$to` and `$cc` variables are not inherited from the parent scope of the Closure passed in `Mail::send`.

Both variables have to be specified in the use language construct. <sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)</sup>

```
Mail::send('contact.email.contact-admin', $data, function ($message) use ($enquiry, $to, $cc) {
    $message->from('no-reply@********.com.au', '********');
    $message->replyTo('no-reply@********.com.au', '********');
    $message->subject($enquiry);
    $message->to($to);
    $message->cc($cc);
});
```